# Why do 2 indistinguishable particles, with two potential paths, always travel down the same path?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment

. Another key experiment uses two photons that can each travel along two different optical fibre paths, a total of four possible outcomes. When the photons are indistinguishable from one another, quantum interference means they bunch together and always take the same path

they are distinguishable, though – for example, if one is a red wavelength and the other is blue – they sometimes take different paths. The more distinct they are – the further apart their wavelengths, say – the more likely this is to happen.

Read more: https://www.newscientist.com/article/2232762-photon-trick-lets-you-bend-the-rules-of-quantum-physics/#ixzz6EY4ROUOF

Read more: https://www.newscientist.com/article/2232762-photon-trick-lets-you-bend-the-rules-of-quantum-physics/#ixzz6EY3hfkfx

I thought that if you don't look, or measure, all quantum particles take all possible paths....   Regardless of differences, or lack thereof....

Comment: What do you mean by quantum interference? If it is dependent on the frequency of the photon, wouldn’t that change in the two cases?

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that if you don't look, or measure, all quantum particles take all possible paths.... Regardless of differences, or lack thereof....

This anthropocentric thought is the problem. It is **interactions** that determine the probability of a particle to be at an (x,y,z,t) . *Looking* and *measuring* involve  interactions, but interactions between particles are [modeled](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html)  [mathematically](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) and do not need a person to *look* at them or *measure* them.

So the "*all quantum particles take all possible paths"* is not true. There is a **probability** of taking a path determined by the boundary conditions of the solutions for the particular experimental set up. Other wise how could we do experiments with particle beams? They all come on the same trajectories hitting similar atoms, because the experimenters made the boundary conditions of the beam creation such that there is an overwhelming probability to have the same trajectories.